# Why the hang() method is only getting executed for one time?

Tags: java, multithreading, mocking, freeze

```
class Demo{

    static void hang(){  // Freezes/Hangs the program for some seconds.
        for(int i=0 ; i<100000 ; i++){
            for(int j=0 ; j<10000 ; j++){
                for(int k=0 ; k<10000 ; k++){
                    int b = 5%12000;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        System.out.print("Loading");
        hang();
        for(int it=0 ; it<5 ; it++)
        {
            System.out.print(".");
            hang();
        }
    }
}
```

The task of `hang()` method is to **hang/freeze** the program for certain time (I know there are other ways to freeze a program, but I want to show it by using for loop).
But when I am executing this, the first `hang()` call, below  the `System.out.print("Loading")` is taking a certain amount of time and giving a delay, the first call in for loop is also giving delay, but the rest of the call (in the for loop) is not taking any time and getting executed instantly and no delay is seen.

Consider all `hang()` calls are getting called(I have checked this by writing a print statement in `hang()` method).

Consider `int b = 5%12000` takes time each time it is called (Checked this even, by replacing it by `if(True)`)

This same code is working in c++ i.e. it shows delay after each "."

Output in c++ was like
`Loading[d].[d].[d].[d].[d].`

But in Java it was like
`Loading[d].[d]....`

`[d]` is delay

And if I replace the `hang()` call with the entire method code in `hang()` method, it works

```
class Demo{

    static void hang(){  // Freezes/Hangs the program for some seconds.
        for(int i=0 ; i<100000 ; i++){
            for(int j=0 ; j<10000 ; j++){
                for(int k=0 ; k<10000 ; k++){
                    int b = 5%12000;
                }
            }
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        System.out.print("Loading");
        hang();
        for(int it=0 ; it<5 ; it++)
        {
            System.out.print(".");
            for(int i=0 ; i<100000 ; i++){
                for(int j=0 ; j<10000 ; j++){
                    for(int k=0 ; k<10000 ; k++){
                        int b = 5%12000;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good optimizer could figure out that `hang()` does nothing - it has no side-effects (apart from taking time) and produces no outputs.  Therefore it optimizes to 'nothing'.

I suspect that is what is happening.

The reason you see a couple of 'full' executions is that the just-in-time compiler did not immediately get turned loose on that routine.